# Where is my log files located?

Tags: java, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

While visiting site ,browser sends log file which contains information like ip address and username of PC, click events and so on to server.

can i see that log file location and how can i edit it?

I want The path to file where server should write log messages.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store Console output of Python Selenium program in to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965426/how-to-store-console-output-of-python-selenium-program-in-to-file)

Comment: See my edited question @JeffC

Comment: No I am not asking about console log.Please read my question carefully.I m asking about kind of Log file information is automatically reported by our browser each time you make a request to access (i.e., visit) a web page. @DebanjanB

Comment: Why do you think there is a log file that is created while you browse? Your question is still unclear and lacking a LOT of information. Clarify your question and provide some research details on what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you want is any info that the webDriver sends to the server (what browser you are using, your IP, passwords/logins etc). You might be able to get such information from the webdriver's cookies/session.

I've never actually used them (or needed any info from them), so your best bet is to see how you can get any "Session info" or "Cookies" from your webdriver.

From a quick search on google, I found this that might be helpful (commands to get the cookies etc). Try to see what info they provide by debugging.
[Cookie Handling in Selenium WebDriver](https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html)